# Converting xls to xlsx using xlrd

Tags: openpyxl, xlsx, xls, xlrd

I am using the exact script below (except the file path) to try to convert xls to xlsx. The script is successful but not producing any output. Am I missing something basic like inputting some variable values or file names, or not saving the file properly as a xlsx?

```
    import xlrd
    import os
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
    filenames = os.listdir("file_path")

    for fname in filenames:
        if fname.endswith(".xls"):
            def cvt_xls_to_xlsx(fname):
                book_xls = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
                book_xlsx = Workbook()

                sheet_names = book_xls.sheet_names()
                for sheet_index in range(0,len(sheet_names)):
                    sheet_xls = book_xls.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[sheet_index])
                    if sheet_index == 0:
                        sheet_xlsx = book_xlsx.active
                        sheet_xlsx.title = sheet_names[sheet_index]
                    else:
                        sheet_xlsx = book_xlsx.create_sheet(title=sheet_names[sheet_index])

                    for row in range(0, sheet_xls.nrows):
                        for col in range(0, sheet_xls.ncols):
                            sheet_xlsx.cell(row = row+1 , column = col+1).value = sheet_xls.cell_value(row, col)

  cvt_xls_to_xlsx(fname)    
  book_xlsx.save(fname.xlsx)
```

I have updated the above script with the last two rows of commands, but I am now getting the following error message:

File "C:\Users\local\Documents\Tasks\Python\Excelconvert.py", line 26, in 
    cvt_xls_to_xlsx(fname)

File "C:\Users\local\Documents\Tasks\Python\Excelconvert.py", line 10, in cvt_xls_to_xlsx
    book_xls = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)

File "C:\Users\local\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

File "C:\Users\local\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

File "C:\Users\local\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])

File "C:\Users\local\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'# - Copy'

What does the '# - Copy' mean? I have seen others suggest it relates to the file format  but usually that is an xml error, and not my above. Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: The function `cvt_xlsx_to_xlsx` is never called.

Comment: Thanks Charlie - are you able to help with the above?